# Ignoring the last value in a groupby() clause

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

I was wondering if this was possible. I currently have a line of code that accumulatively adds all the values in my `Total Time (s)` column, grouped by the value contained in the column `CycleNumber`. Into a list called `cycle_times`. I'm achieving this right now as follows:

```
cycle_times = raw_data['Total Time (s)'].diff().fillna(0).groupby(interim_output['CycleNumber']).cumsum()
```

This provides an output at the end of the group by, like this:

```
print(interim_output['CycleNumber'][328:334])

328    1
329    1
330    1
331    2
332    2
333    2

print(cycle_times[328:334])

328    65.643
329    65.673
330    65.994
331    66.008
332       0.0
333     0.251
```

Which is almost what I want. However, as you can see, the first instance of number 2 in `CycleNumber` is adding to the total (the short time it takes for the machine to reset in its reading). Is there anyway of using groupBy, and telling it to ignore this value, or forcing it to reset at the change of `CycleNumber`? If I had it this way, my desired output would be this:

```
print(cycle_times[328:334])

328    65.643
329    65.673
330    65.994
331       0.0
332       0.0
333     0.251
```

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is one .groupby(df['CycleNumber']) missing to get what you want, see "cycle_times_V1". However, the resulting code is then very unreadable. I added a version which gives the same output but is much more explicit, see "cycle_times_V2"

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"CycleNumber": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
                   "Total Time (s)": list(range(6))})

df["cycle_times_before"]  = df['Total Time (s)'].diff().fillna(0).groupby(df['CycleNumber']).cumsum()
df["cycle_times_V1"] = df['Total Time (s)'].groupby(df['CycleNumber']).diff().fillna(0).groupby(df['CycleNumber']).cumsum()

# this gives the same, but is much more explicit
df["cycleStartTime"] = np.nan
for groupItem, df_group in df.groupby(by="CycleNumber"):
    df.loc[df_group.index,"cycleStartTime"] = df_group["Total Time (s)"].min()
df["cycle_times_V2"] = df["Total Time (s)"] - df["cycleStartTime"]
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your answer for my code but it threw up a `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable` error

Comment: Ok, I managed to get your code to work, but `totalTimePerCycleStartZero` is just adding up all the figures into one big total accumulatively and isn't my desired output shown

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood...
Lets assume, all your data is in one dataframe df, not split in raw_data and interim_output.
So, in that dataframe df, the column "Total Time (s)" is steadily increasing, each row represents one measurement, belonging to a cycle definded by "CycleNumber".
Now you want a column "cycle_times", which starts at zero for the first item of a cycle and cumsum the time, so that the last entry of the cycle gives the total cycle time. Is that correct? If so, I think you just need another .groupby(df['CycleNumber']), see modified answer.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help again, but the second group by is adding a second zero right at the start, and therefore throwing the actual `cumsum()` out by a few milliseconds. I think I might just stick to my original solution and see if it is acceptable, but I appreciate the help nonetheless.